# getting quantity from one table and substract from another table quantity using php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
include ("../database.php");
include ("../session.php");
include ("../Utype.php");
$SEARCH=$_POST["SEARCH"];
$BARCODE=$_POST["BARCODE"];
if (isset($SEARCH))
    {
        $sql2=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stock_count_tb ");
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql2))
            {
                $sql3=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product_stock_fullsum ");
                while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($sql3))
                    {
                        $CORRECTQTY=$row1['Qty']-$row['QTY'];
                        $Prod_ID=$row['ST_PRODUCT_ID'];
                        $sql5=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `product_stock_correctstock` (`Prod_ID`, `Qty`, `Free`, `PO_ID`, `Expire_Date`) 
                                           VALUES ('$Prod_ID', '$CORRECTQTY', '0', '', '00:00:0000');");

                    }       
            }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link href="../css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="BrightSide.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="../jquerylib.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="Sales_deduct_stock.php" name="foo" method="POST">
      <table width="700" border="0">
        <tr><th width="183" scope="row"><div align="right" class="style12">ENTER PRODUCT BARCODE :</div></th>
          <th width="501" scope="row"><div align="left"><label><input name="SEARCH" type="submit" class="button" id="SEARCH" value="ADD TO STOCK" /></label></div></th></tr>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you expect to see as a result? What have you tried to make the results you get look like what you see?

Comment: You can do the entire thing using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`, where the `SELECT` is a `JOIN` between the two tables.

Comment: You're subtracting EVERY quantity in the first table from EVERY quantity in the second table. Is that what you want? Or should you just be subtracting quantities from corresponding products in the two tables? You either need to join the tables or use a `WHERE` clause in the second query.

Comment: I need only subtract product_stock_fullsum table's Quantity from stock_count_tb table's Quantity and need to insert that result in to product_stock_correctstock table.there have lot of records to substract..

Comment: please help me for this..i think problem in While loop..help met solve this